# What is the purpose of the capacitors on the input and output of this circuit?

Tags: capacitor

In the circuit below,  I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of C1, C2, C12, C13, C14, C15.

The circuit takes a differential pulse input and has an amplified differential pulse output.

It's got a low pass filter in the front, so C1 and C2 kind of make sense to shunt some high frequency energy to ground. How do people even choose the capacitance value for caps for that purpose?

The output capacitors C12-C15 make less sense to me. Why is the output AC coupled?

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of the circuit so folks don't have to follow a link. The link might not work in the future at some point then the answers provided become useless.

Comment: You've asked a few questions now - are you aware that it is customary to formally accept the most appropriate answer to each question that you have raised. Of course if there are some questions that haven't received any answers then that's impossible. But also, there may be some questions that have answers that you need clarification on. In the latter case I urge you to pursue clarification so that those questions can be formally completed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 1):

if it helps, here is just the circuit from https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbqnb.jpg referred to in the question

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbqnb.jpg]

also the circuit seems to be linear balanced video amplifier. (or a linear RF voltage amp.)

[image]

[image]

capacitors at input are part of a LP-filter that can prevent self-oscillations if no input is connected (for one)

capacitors at output provide AC-only coupling

Comment: Any idea why there is AC coupling on the output? Regarding the input, I haven't see a low pass filter like that. There's an RLC LPF that has an inductor in series followed by a capacitor and resistor in parallel, which is what I see here, disregarding the capacitors at the input. How do I find the cutoff frequency when including those input capacitors? It doesn't look like a standard config I can find any references for. Thanks

Comment: I guess write the transfer function and solve for when power is down by 3dB?